# Does this kind of integral rearrangement work?

Tags: integration

I know there isn't any general closed form for $\int{1\over{f(x)}}dx$, but let's say that for some function g(x) the following anti-derivative holds:

$$\int{1\over{f(x)}} dx={g(x)\over{f(x)}}$$

Does it then make sense to let $f(x)=\int f'(x) dx$ and do the following?

$$\int f'(x)dx \int{1\over{f(x)}}dx={g(x)}$$
$$\iint {f'(x)\over{f(x)}}dxdx={g(x)}$$
$$\int ln{|f(x)|}dx=g(x)$$

Or do I need to include the constant of integration in my working when I do this, given that my rearrangement was multiplying through by the $f(x)$, where there would be an extra $+Cf(x)$ on the right hand side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't combine two indefinite integrals with the same variable into a double integral that way, i.e. you can't write $$\int a(x)\; dx \int b(x)\; dx = \iint a(x) b(x)\; dx\; dx$$
Try some examples, e.g. $a(x) = x$, $b(x) = x^2$.

Comment: Ah right of course. I am stupid. I think I've even asked a similar question before (somewhere else) and got a similar answer with a similar example. Yeah and especially since technically they're treated more like summations should have made it obvious to me. Thanks. I tried to Google things like multiplication and integration and all I found out about was geometric integration instead haha.